# Unescape during XSLT transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm transforming an XML document using XSLT into XHTML, using Saxon, XSLT 2.0 compliant.

Within my XML documents I have nodes like so (truncated here for brevity):

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.write('&lt;script&gt;')
  </script>
```

What I want to be able to do is unesacape the escaped characters so that `&lt;` becomes `<` and `&gt;` becomes `>`, ideally only when they occur within the script nodes.

The final output would then be:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  document.write('<script>')
  </script>
```

Is this possible, and any suggestions as to how?

Comment: Joel, I am curious, since when is Xalan XSLT 2.0 compliant? To my knowledge (http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) it implements XSLT 1.0 and various extensions.

Comment: Oops - My Bad. I'm using Saxon. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `html` serialization method, `script` content doesn't get escaped.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method

> The `html` output method should not
>   perform escaping for the content of
>   the `script` and `style` elements

**Update**

As Dr. @Michael Kay have commented, if you are generating XHTML (and sending with correct MIME type) for browsers wich understand XHTML, then you don't need to worry about unescaping. Also, it should be pointed out that inline script is not considered good practice.

If you still want to generate XHTML following guidelines for legacy browsers, with `xml` serialization method, you can declare `script` content as CDATA section.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method

> The `cdata-section-elements` attribute
>   contains a whitespace-separated list
>   of QNames. Each QName is expanded into
>   an expanded-name using the namespace
>   declarations in effect on the
>   `xsl:output` element in which the
>   QName occurs; if there is a default
>   namespace, it is used for QNames that
>   do not have a prefix. The expansion is
>   performed before the merging of
>   multiple `xsl:output` elements into a
>   single effective `xsl:output` element.
>   If the expanded-name of the parent of
>   a text node is a member of the list,
>   then the text node should be output as
>   a CDATA section

As example:

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="xhtml:script xhtml:style"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

Comment: Correct. If you're using the HTML output method, the characters won't be escaped. If you're using the XHTML output method, they will be escaped but you don't need to worry about it so long as the browser understands XHTML (and if it doesn't, then why generate it?)

Comment: @Michael Kay: I agree: when generating XHTML, you don't need unescape because browser should understand XML properly. Adding that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks both. I'll review my serialisation settings.

Comment: @Michael Kay - you are indeed correct. There was no issue with the transformation and rendering of the script tags (I'm serialising as xhtl). The error in displaying page rendering  was caused by something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping

Comment: Yes indeed. I also found this duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646194/xsl-character-escape-problem

Comment: I think this does what I need:    <xsl:template match="script">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Comment: If you want the `type="text/javascript"` in the result too then do an `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` inside of the `xsl:copy`.