# XSL - Escaping an apostrophe during xsl:when test

Tags: xslt

I have the following code which appears to be failing.

```
<xsl:when test="$trialSiteName = 'Physician&apos;s Office'">
```

Also, visual studio is complaining saying

> "Expected end of expression, found 's"

How am I supposed to escape the character?

---

XSLT v1.0.  Apache XSL-FO processor.

Comment: Could your problem be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646194/xsl-character-escape-problem ? If so, try: &amp;apos;

Comment: @Dan Lehmann - That did not work.  I don't think those issues are the same.

Comment: As a workaround, I am going to remove this character in C# before passing it into the XSLT processor.  This won't work for all situations so I will leave this question open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Much more simple -- use**:

```
   <xsl:when test="$trialSiteName = &quot;Physician&apos;s Office&quot;">
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Declare a variable:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
   ```
2. Use the variable like this in the `<xsl:when>` clause:

   ```
   <xsl:when test="$trialSiteName = concat('Physician', $apos, 's Office')">
   ```

Comment: +1. You can also use `<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>`.

Answer (score 1):

in between `&quot;` you can add what ever special characters you want.

```
<xsl:when test="$trialSiteName = &quot;Physician's what ever special charactors plainly add Office&quot;">
```

Answer (score 0):

`&apos;` works for XPath 1.0. If you are using XSLT 2.0 with XPath 2.0 try double apostrophe:

```
<xsl:when test="$trialSiteName = 'Physician''s Office'">
```

Look for a full explanation by Dimitre Novatchev in his answer [Escape single quote in xslt concat function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887281/escape-single-quote-in-xslt-concat-function#2888544)

Comment: This did not work.  Visual studio still displays error.  Logic does not execute correctly.

Comment: @_Phillip: Yes, it *is* possible to use the same technique :)